# How can I pass values using .html(data) on javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

On javascript I have the following code:

```
if (id == 'Log') {

            $('#fileList').html(data);
```

Depending by the ID, I open a new html page. The problem is I need the ID even on the other html page. How can I pass the id to the other page?

Comment: You can use `queryParams` or `localStorage` or `cookies`

Comment: when you say 'i open a new HTML page' do you mean with something like window.open(...) ?

Answer (score 0):

you could put it in a cookie.

```
function writeCookie(name,value,ttl){
        var eol = new Date( ttl > 0 ? ( new Date().getTime() + ttl ) : 0 );
        document.cookie = name +"="+ value +"; expires="+ eol.toGMTString() +"; path=/";
}
```